# Iterating PDO queries with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have this problem I can't figure out,
I query the DB this way:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT customer_name FROM active_users WHERE a_id= ?');
$stmt->execute(array($a_id));
$c_name = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
API::writeToLog('CMD=leave , Customer_Name = ' . $c_name->customer_name, $customer_name);
```

This: $c_name->customer_name gives the following error :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

How can I iterate my database, and whats the difference between fetch and fetchAll ? which should I use?

This is the DB schema:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a_id          | varchar(40)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| token         | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| nick          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ip            | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| customer_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

thanx!

EDIT: fixed a typo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an if condition to check whether the record exists.

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT customer_name FROM active_users WHERE udid = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($udid));
if ($c_name = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  API::writeToLog('CMD=leave , Customer_Name = ' . $c_name->customer_name, $customer_name);
}
```

For [fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), it returns all the records at once.

As @Darragh pointed out, you have a typo for `$c_name`.

Comment: +1 always good practice to check your returned assignment values

Comment: when using the fetchAll like this: $messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);      should I use 'if' to check the returned value as well?     if so, iterating over the pdo objects will be as followed ? :   foreach ($messages as $message) { ... }

Comment: @Li3ro You just need iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

Typo? Should it not be `$cname->customer_name` instead of `$c_name->customer_name`?

**EDIT**

To be specific, you're assiging your return object to `$cname`:

```
$cname = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

But you're referring to `$c_name` on the next line:

```
API::writeToLog('CMD=leave , Customer_Name = ' . $c_name->customer_name, $customer_name);
```

Comment: You right, its a typo when editing the question, not in code.. sry